# Prevent bubbling without Jquery

Tags: asp.net, javascript

When I move mouse over the container panel, the child panel is displayed but as soon as i move mouse over the child panel, the mouseout event is triggered and panel get hidden.

This is simplified version of my code because panels are located inside gridview and therefore i can't use document.getElementById("panelchild") as it is (the js will get the specific id latter), but for now i want to make it work for this simple case.

This is the partial script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPanel(e) {
            // e = e || window.event;
            //  var evtSrc = e.target || e.srcElement;          

            var panel = document.getElementById("panelchild")
            if (panel.style.display == "none")
                panel.style.display = "";
            else
                panel.style.display = "none";           
        }

</script>
```

This is the markup:

```
<asp:Panel id="panelContainer" runat="server" onmouseover="ShowPanel(event)" onmouseout="ShowPanel(event)" >
   <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTitle" runat="server" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;" Text="This is title" NavigateUrl="www" />            
   <asp:Panel id="panelchild" runat="server"  style="display:none" >                
        <a id="A1" href="javascript: void(0);" style="text-decoration: none;">
             <img src="mylocalsite/images/Misc_Edit.gif" style="border:0px;float:left;" /> 
         </a>  
   </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Not much you can do as long as panelChild is inside panelContainer.

Comment: I can move chidpanel outside but with this I would have to add events also to child.

Comment: why you refuse to use jQuery, if you are using other frameworks its possible to use jQuery as well using noconflict();

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the event listener to the **panelContainer** until the **panelChild** receives an *onmouseover* event. In fact, you probably don't need the *onmouseover* event on the **panelContainer** element at all. Just add *onmouseout* to **panelChild** and you should be fine.

One more thing. The way you have your "show/hide" statements written is a little weird. Here is what I would do:

```
        if (panel.style.display == "block")
            panel.style.display = "none";
        else
            panel.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: But panelChild is hidden, it's should be displayed when user hovers over the title

Comment: @mariki: The way your code is written **panelChild** will be displayed when the mouse hovers over the **panelContainer** and hidden when it exits same. If you want the display to happen when you hover over **lnkTitle** then handle the hover on *onmouseover* for **lnkTitle**; in any case, handle the *onmouseout* on **panelChild**. If this is not the behavior you want, please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: the child panel should be disaplyed when mouse over the title and stay displayed when mouse over the childpanel.

Comment: Then add the onmouseover listener to the title to show the panel, and add the onmouseout listener to the panelChild to hide the panel.

Comment: I tired that, as soon as try to move cursor form title to childpanel, child panel disappears.

Comment: Again, childPanel needs to be displayed when mouse is over the title, and ofcourse, when the mouse is over the childpanel itself.

Comment: OK, here's what you do:

1. create a new function that sets a timeOut that calls the show/hide function after a certain period of time *unless canceled*
2. add an onmouseout to the lnkTitle that calls this new timeout function and an onmouseover that directly calls the show/hide function.
3. add an onmouseout to the panelChild that directly calls the show/hide function and cancels the timeout function

Answer (score 0):

Or pull the child outside of the parent container and reposition it to underneath the element using javascript.

Comment: And where should I set the events?

Comment: If I understand  correctly, you move the panel that you want to popup outside the container panel, you have the container panel keep the events, and then when the panel gets shown, you add code to move the child panel to right underneath the control you want the panel to show for, which I assume you want to target the link.

Comment: and how I do it? p.s the child panel should appear right to the link.

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/7911/element-dimensions/ is a utility to get the dimensions of an element, and after getting the left/top, you calculate the new left/top to place the div, setting the style.top or style.left accordingly.  JQuery or MS AJAX have some built-in functions if you are using each, doesn't seem like you are from your other comment?

Answer (score 0):

Also, since you are using .NET, there is an Ajax Control Toolkit extender, the HoverMenuExtender, that shows or hides a panel when mousing over/out, that you can easily use to set this up.  There is a demo at asp.net/ajax

Comment: I know there that there are tools for it, if I wanted to use them I would use jquery. But I don't.